# How to remove :focus pseudo class via react/ next js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I'm using next js for my web application, I'm using `:focus` to display a button tooltip, it still stays even when the options are selected. I would like to remove this `:focus` class by hook or by crook.

Here is my css for reference:

```css
.icon-container-interaction:focus .post-cell-options{
    opacity: 1;
    top: 56px;
    right: 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 6px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    visibility: visible;
}


.post-cell-options{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffffe3;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    transition: 0.2s;
    float: right;
    color: #000;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard without seeing the code itself for you component but it sounds like you could try something where you create a ref for the button and then call `blur()` when you click on an option (which takes that element out of focus, effectively removing that pseudo class.

basic idea without knowing the full setup:

```
const buttonRef = React.useRef(null)

....

return <>
  <ButtonTooltip ref={buttonRef} />
  <Options onClick={() => buttonRef.current.blur()} />
</>
```

with class components:

```
constructor(props) { 
  super(props); 
  this.buttonRef = React.createRef()
}

return <>
  <ButtonTooltip ref={this.buttonRef} />
  <Options onClick={() => this.buttonRef.current.blur()} />
</>
```

Comment: is there a way I can use this in a class component ?

Comment: yes the class component equivalent is with `React.createRef` and you bind it to the constructor... edited the original post with that code